# Rotate subdivided plane with x+y locked

Tags: modeling

I’m wrapping my head around one issue that seems pretty simple:
Cube with loop cut.

Picture: I want to rotate the top planes and keep their x/y coordinates.

- I don’t want to do it with proportional editing for multiple reasons

I want to start out with a flat plane.

Additional: Is there a command to align edges/vertices between two endpoints?

[image: Desired output]

Comment: Next time use more isometric view.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Shear Transform from the Mesh > Transforms menu. I see you are still in 2.79. I would really recommend updating, because the Shear Tool in 2.80, which does the same thing is much more intuitive to use.

Comment: shear tool works fine, thanks.
Only thing: I have to be in iso frontview to shear along y

Answer (score 1):

Or move one edge up the z-axis and the opposite one down by **the same** amount. Be careful not to cross the loopcut line, though. Shear tool, 2.7x at least, seems to work only along the x-axis and with faces so you need to rotate your object before.

Comment: And note that once you’ve moved them to different *z*-positions, you can just Scale Along Z (`s` `z`) to adjust the shear magnitude more precisely.